# How to add prefix in httaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

**Could you help me to make a rewrite?**

I have a website.
URLs on my website looks like:

https://example.com/

https://example.com/category/first-category-name/

https://example.com/first-category-name/first-post-name/

---

I want:
On click any of this URLs changing: getting prefix with GET parameter.

prefix is: https://example.com/love/out.php?s=80&u=

---

I've tried:

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/love/out.php?s=80&u=https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

---

Result should be:

https://example.com/love/out.php?s=80&u=https://example.com/

https://example.com/love/out.php?s=80&u=https://example.com/category/first-category-name/

https://example.com/love/out.php?s=80&u=https://example.com/first-category-name/first-post-name/

Comment: And your question is _what_ ? So far you only stated what you _want_ , but not what the issue is, so what your actual question is.

Comment: How to convert https://example.com/ to https://example.com/love/out.php?s=80&u=https://example.com/ with .htaccess?

Comment: You posted an approach for that yourself, so that hardly is your actual question. If your attempt does not work then your question might be how to fix it or what is wrong, but you ask none of that. And if you would, then you would have to add a few more details like why do you think it does not work and how that shows.